# How to open outlook.com WebLink in conversation view

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-app, outlook.com

How do I open a `WebLink` received from the outlook restful api in conversation view? (kinda like how in gmail if you open an email, you can see all the previous messages and attachments)

Here is an example of a`WebLink`: "https://outlook.live.com/owa/?ItemID=AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC0wMTlkLWQ1NjktMDACLTAwCgBGAAADTWCDb%2BAeaU2aAmthBvoOHgcAFp9IUDCaPEG5aPJFjPaf3AAAAgEMAAAAFp9IUDCaPEG5aPJFjPaf3AAAAJKI4ZYAAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem&path="

Thanks